# Difference between Keras and tensorflow implementation of LSTM with dropout

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I was reviewing the documentation for the LSTM cell in tensorflow and Keras. In particular, I want to apply dropout as well. Here is what I have in Keras and would like to apply the same LSTM cell in tensorflow:

```
cell = LSTM(num_units_2, return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout)(net)
```

Therefore, I know that I need to use `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` in tensorflow with `num_units = num_units_2`. Second, I need a `DropoutWrapper` as:

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell)
```

Now, I want to apply `dropout` and `recurrent_dropout` similar to the Keras code. Therefore, I found that tensorflow's implementation of dropout will apply a different dropout mask at every time step unless `variational_recurrent` is set to True (Yet I'm not sure how variational_recurrent works in details).

Additionally, I'm not sure if the LSTM in Keras apply different Mask at each time step as well.

Second, I was confused about the difference between the `output_keep_prob` and the `state_keep_prob` as both mention:

*output_keep_prob*: unit Tensor or float between 0 and 1, output keep probability; if it is constant and 1, no output dropout will be added...

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What variational dropout does

As far as I know, the main novelty of variational dropout is using the same dropout mask for all unrolled steps (as you said).

### Difference between `output_keep_prob` and the `state_keep_prob`

`output_keep_prob` is the dropout rate applied to the output (h) of the LSTM cell where `state_keep_prob` is the dropout rate applied to the cell (c) of the LSTM state.

### Dropout choice in Keras

Looking at the `_generate_dropout_mask` method in the [LSTM source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2220-L2232) and [its use for the LSTMCell](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1855-L1868) of Keras, I think Keras LSTM uses variational recurrent dropout only for the recurrent connections (i.e. `self._recurrent_dropout_mask`) . But I'm not 100% confident about this.

Comment: Then what I am using a GRU, I have only one output h; how will the `state_keep_prob` change the output? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Actually a look,
Seems GRU does something paculiar. The GRUCell returns the same state twice in the `call()` function. Then it seems to use the `state_dropout` mask when feeding the state to the cell as a recurrent input, and the `output_dropout` when giving the output for that state ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L748-L761).